# Checkout page is empty

Tags: magento2, checkout, fatal-error, magento-2.1.1

I tried to run Magento 2.1.1 in my server but it seems that my checkout page isn't displaying anything, just header and footer.

**Some error is generated:**

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 826253 bytes) in
>   `/home/ourshop/public_html/migrate/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php`
>   on line 311

Comment: Refer this = http://wdevelop.com/magento-2-allowed-memory-size-exhausted/ - How to increase the memory may be it will help you

Comment: may be you have print log somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Open a php.ini in a text editor.

Change the value of memory_limit to one of the values at the beginning of this section.

For example,

```
memory_limit=2G
```

Required for PHP 5.6, recommended for PHP 5.5. Locate always_populate_raw_post_data, uncomment it if necessary, and set it as follows:

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

You can get more information : [Required PHP settings](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html)

Comment: I have set memory limit in php.ini but not working.other solveution

Comment: It require restart apache server and remove var folder.